# How to specify an optstring in the getopt function?

Tags: c, getopt

I'm not sure how to correctly use `optstring` in the `getopt` function in C.

How should that string be formatted? I saw examples where letters are next to each other, sometimes separated by a semicolon, sometimes by two semicolons.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is just a string, and each character of this string represents an option. If this option requires an argument, you have to follow the option character by `:`.

For example, `"cdf:g"` accepts the options `c`, `d`, `f`, and `g`; `f` requires an additional argument.

An option in command line looks like `-option`, so you can use the options `-c`, `-d`, `-f argument` and `-g`.

Comment: And then in command line options have dash and are separated with space? And if some option is with `:` then in command line the following typed input after space is taken as argument?

Comment: Now I understand it:)  Thank you!

Comment: When the option has an argument, the value is found in the (global) variable `optarg` that's declared in the header where [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) is declared (`<unistd.h>`).  Two colons is an extension that indicates the following argument is optional.

Answer (score 13):

The `getopt(3)` manpage makes it pretty clear :

- the string itself is used for specifying the legal options that can appear on the commandline,
- if the option is followed by a `:`, then that option has a required parameter - not specifying it will cause the function to fail,
- if the option is followed by a `::`, then that option has an optional parameter.

The options are one-letter identifiers. For example, specifying a string like `aB:cD::` as the `optstring` will mean that your program takes options `a`, `B` with a required parameter, `c`, and `D` with an optional parameter.

Answer (score 4):

If colon `:`is followed by a char or string means this option must require the argument 
and if there are no colon means no arguments

for more details do `man 3 getopt`
or visit the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt) or [manpage](http://ss64.com/bash/getopts.html)

Comment: It should be if a character is followed by `:`.?

Comment: According to [getopt manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html): 
"The argument optstring is a string of recognized option characters; if a character is followed by a colon, the option takes an argument."